# Error with Html Webpack Plugin when I start my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

When I start my new react app I get an error:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ../../#React/react-sneakers/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:18  2:2)
      at runLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
  ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../#React/react-sneakers/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:18  2:2)
      at runLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
      at processResult (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:753:19)
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:855:5
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:185:11
      at loadLoader (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:33:11)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:18  2:2)
      at runLoaders (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at C:\Users\1\Desktop\works\#React\react-sneakers\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
```

Node v: 16.13.2
npm v: 8.5.0

What should I do?

This happened when I reinstalled Node.js
Perhaps this is due to some error during reinstallation
Please, if you have encountered such a problem, write what helped you.

Comment: Delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock`) and install dependencies again

Comment: Doesn't work, the same error

Comment: @Nikita Please share your Webpack configuration.

Comment: I don't use a configuration, I just created my react app running command `npx create-react-app`